# Character initialisation using another character array

Tags: c++, string

I have `char a[] = "abc"`.

I need to do: `char b [] = a` i.e essentially copy a to b without having to specify the size of b.

How can I do this in cpp?

Comment: `char a[]` in this case is a character array. If you need just one char then you can write `char a = 'a';`

Comment: You're stuck if you stick with a character array, but `std::string b = a;` makes the whole nightmare go away.

Comment: @user4581301 : so no way do to with char array then?  String only?

Comment: Just a nitpick, that's a C string, not a character array. C strings have null terminators and character arrays do not. Or at least that's my understanding...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts char b[3]="abc" is an error. I guess this adds the '\0' too. My bad : I guess the null is added when i assign a string. If i do character wise 3 is just fine

Comment: @BhumiSinghal `"abc"` is a string literal defining array of 4 chars the last item of which contains 0.

Comment: @VIT : thanks :) just figured it out

Comment: @BhumiSinghal -- Arrays are dumb.  They know nothing about their size.  If you want this type of functionality, you have to go to a higher-level construct, such as `std::string` or some other container class that has `=` overloaded to do such copying.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal The problem is C++ doesn't have a native string type.  There are characters arrays, and using them you can make cstrings, but it is a lot of manual hassle.  `std::string` wraps all that hassle under a nice pretty bow that is easy to use.  Unless you really have a need to do otherwise, `std::string` should be you go to for string operations.

Comment: If all the sizes are known at compile time there might be some template wizardry or macro monstrosity that will do what you want, but I'm not good enough with templates to recommend anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is incorrect. Arrays are fully aware of their size, it's encoded in their type, just like `std::array`. `int[10]` is an array of 10 `int`s. You can obtain the size of a C array using the ratio between the `sizeof` the array and the `sizeof` an element. You can also obtain it through template deduction. C arrays decay easily and frequently to pointers, but they are clearly distinct types. Having said that, please to not take this comment as encouragement to use of C arrays where safer and more powerful alternatives exist.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts -- just a bit of clarification on terminology. A **C string** is an array of `char` that's terminated by a nul character. Functions that take C strings treat that terminator as the end of the string. A **string literal** such as `"abc"` is an array of `const char`; it contains the characters between the quotes **and** a nul terminator, so it Can be used as a C string. A `char` array will have a nul terminator if you put one in it, and won't if you don't. If it has a nul terminator it can be used as a C string; if it doesn't, it can't.

Comment: @PeteBecker A string isn't an array. It's a sequence of characters that may be stored in an array.

Comment: @M.M -- a **C string** is **always** an array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no assignment operator overload for plain arrays. 
You have to use some [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function like this:

```
char a[] = "abc";
decltype(a) b;
std::copy( std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b) );
```

Using [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) we get the type of array `a` and use that to declare array `b`.

But this is still not very C++ish in my opinion.

As commenters suggested, simply use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). If you can't use `std::string` please explain why.

```
std::string a = "abc";
std::string b = a;
```

Much cleaner and less things that can go wrong.

Comment: You don't really need the `/ sizeof(a[0])` since `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to always be one.  That said it does make it less brittle if the type ever changes.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes the latter was the intend.

Comment: You could use `decltype(a) b;` instead of `char b[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])];`

Comment: @rex That's pretty cool.  Hadn't ever thought about doing that.